# combine c# class and vb.net classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, class

I am using asp.net 2012 and have c# class project where I would like to include some existing vb.net classes.

What would be the best way to be able to use both c# and vb.net classes?

Comment: You can keep the VB.Net classes in a separate project?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as "ASP.NET 2012". You mean either "ASP.NET 4.5" or "Visual Studio 2012".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either convert the vb.net classes into C# or put the vb.net classes into their own assembly and add a reference to the assembly.

Comment: The vb.net classes are from 3.5 and can be a pain to convert. I will take your advice and reference the library.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

put the VB.NET classes in a project of its own and then reference that project, just as you would any third party control.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, one of the alternatives is to convert c# to vb.net or vice-versa.
You can find many pages in the internet to do that, like these ones:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

If you convert the code from one language to the other make sure you test the changes properly.

If you decide to keep VB.NET code in a separate Visual Studio project and reference it in the C# code you need to ensure that the VB.NET code is CLS compliant. This is a good starting point:

[Writing CLS-Compliant Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

See also:

[Cross-Language Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2c7tshk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Make C# a .NET library and include it in your VB.NET/ASP.NET project.

Follow this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx for more info...